# Jersey exception is not clear

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to create a method which gets a mandatory parameter. I'm doing it this way:

```
@Path("/insertPerson")
@GET
@UnitOfWork
public short insertPerson(@NotNull @QueryParam("person") Person per)
{ ... }
```

When I try to send a GET request with no parameters, I am receiving back the following HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /person/insertPerson/. Reason:

        <pre>    Not Found</pre>
    </p>
    <hr>
    <i>
        <small>Powered by Jetty://</small>
    </i>
    <hr/>
</body>
```

Is there a way to control what I'm sending back as a result of a null object? Error 404 is not clear enough to know that a null parameter has caused this issue. Is there also a way to send a simple string back instead of an HTML page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I eventually did was searching for a way to automatically create an exception upon error. So I used an ExceptionMapper which will create a response with the exception message:

```
@Provider
public class CustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception>
{
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) 
    {
        String error = exception.getMessage();
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(error).type("text/plain").build();  
    }
}
```